# Why doesn't the ids of an Entity start incrementing at 1 during Fixtures loading?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've made Fixtures for two of my entities that have a ManyToMany relation. My `ColorFixtures` load, then my `FabricFixtures`. As you can see in code below, I add a color to my fabric by using the `ColorRepository`. I always get following error :

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\Fabric::addColor() must be an instance of App\Entity\Color, null given, called in /var/www/html/src/DataFixtures/FabricFixtures.php on line 44
```

So I tried to dig a little deeper, and the thing is, at the end of the loading of ColorFixtures, the ids of my colors go from 222 to 241 (since I've tried a lot of times to load these fixtures, at one point the ids must have been lower numbers, because the next loading I dumped, the ids where from 242 to 261, and I tried a unique one before that was 221).

So of course when I use the ColorRepository to find id 1 to 20 in the FabricFixtures, the color is null because at that point the ids are 200 times higher.

When I dump the colors after the Fixtures process (in a Controller), the ids are correctly set from 1 to 20. Thus my question : **Why doesn't the ids of an Entity start incrementing at 1 during Fixtures loading?** I guess there's some cache of previous loadings of Fixtures, but I don't really know, and if that's indeed the case, why there's even a cache. How could I make sure that the ids always start incrementing at 1 so that I can safely add colors to my fabrics?

Note: even after running `bin/console cache:clear`, the "temporary" ids are still increasing (last time I dumped: 282 to 301).

Note 2: I don't know if that matters, but I'm using Symfony 5, and doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle 3.3

Note 3: I think [this](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/issues/277) is a related issue and I understand after reading the maintainer's answer that I shouldn't depend on the incremented ids of my Entity in the Fixtures of another. Do I understand well? If so, do you have any lead on how I could do to create the relationship between the fabric and the color?

Note 4: Actually, this is a personal project I've been working on for a few months now, aside from work & school, and I had first started developping it with Laravel, then I did it with Symfony to learn the framework, then back to Laravel because I preferred this framework, and now I'm back again (and finally !) on Symfony. And in the Laravel version I just made a FabricColor "Fixtures" where I made DB queries to add the raw ids to the DB table. Is that how I should do it in Symfony to? In the end, shouldn't my question be: **What is the best way to make Fixtures with ManyToMany relations?"**

Thanks a lot!

**FabricFixtures**
(I use the  ̀DependentFixtureInterface` to be sure the ColorFixtures effectively load before the FabricFixtures)

```php
<?php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\Fabric;
use App\Repository\ColorRepository;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\DependentFixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Faker\Factory;

class FabricFixtures extends Fixture implements DependentFixtureInterface
{
    /** @var ColorRepository */
    private $colorRepository;

    /**
     * FabricFixtures constructor.
     * @param ColorRepository $colorRepository
     */
    public function __construct(ColorRepository $colorRepository)
    {
        $this->colorRepository = $colorRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $faker = Factory::create();

        for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++) {
            $fabric = new Fabric();
            $fabric->setBox(rand(1, 30));
            $fabric->setMaterial($faker->word);
            $fabric->setPattern($faker->word);
            $fabric->setState($faker->word);
            $fabric->setThickness($faker->word);
            $fabric->setWidth(rand(100, 500));
            $fabric->setLength(rand(100, 500));
            $fabric->setComment($faker->words(5, true));
            $fabric->addColor($this->colorRepository->find(rand(1, 20)));

            $manager->persist($fabric);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getDependencies()
    {
        return [
            ColorFixtures::class
        ];
    }
}
```

**dump of the color created during loading process**

```
 App\Entity\Color^ {#558
  -id: 221
  -name: "name"
  -code: "code"
  -fabrics: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection^ {#542
    -snapshot: []
    -owner: App\Entity\Color^ {#558}
    -association: array:16 [ …16]
    -em: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager^ {#171 …11}
    -backRefFieldName: "color"
    -typeClass: Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata {#451 …}
    -isDirty: false
    #collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection^ {#545
      -elements: []
    }
    #initialized: true
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at the section `Sharing Objects between Fixtures` in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html). You might also consider adding `dmaicher/doctrine-test-bundle` to reset the database after each test.

Comment: I have already read this section, but is it really "clean" to add a reference to the 20 colors created? I could create the reference in the for loop that creates colors, but that doesn't seem really optimized to me, because if I create 20 references but only uses 4 because I randomly chooses the color that will be added to the fabric, that leaves 16 references not used...
And as for the bundle, I don't want to reset the database since it's not a test: I just want dummy data for development. And when it's in the DB the ids *are* from 1 to 20, it's only in the fixtures that they are way higher.

Comment: It seems that loading fixtures multiple times is in effect testing your code. Testing is good. For production, fixtures should be "set it and forget it".

Comment: Yes, I agree with you that testing is good, but I haven't loaded fixtures multiple times to test my code. I've loaded them again and again to see if the error I got was still there. My goal *is* to set them only once, in development mode, to have objects to work with: I'm not planning on testing the CRUD operations because that will be managed by API Platform; I mostly want those objects to do the front interface. But maybe that's not what fixtures are for? Should they be use only for testing purposes?

Comment: Is it what are you looking for? https://github.com/EnMarche/en-marche.fr/blob/master/src/DataFixtures/ORM/LoadAdherentData.php#L79

Comment: @qdequippe sorry for the late answer and thanks for yours; it could be a solution for my problem (the one I've chosen for the moment is making queries to the liaison table, just as I was doing in the Laravel version of my project), but it's a homemade class, right? And it seems to reset the id in the db, whereas in my case when the `EntityManager` is flushed the ids in the db actually start at 1, it's just in Symfony during the load process that they're not. Actually I would like to have an answer as to *why* the ids in the fixtures process don't start incrementing at 1.